# Сделать код синхронным

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Помогите сделать код синхронным... это функция происходит при клике когда пользователь добавляет новую статью, сначала делаю `POST` потом `GET` чтобы без перезагрузки страниц поменялись данные, прочитал про синхронный код про `promise` немного изучил много попробовал и не получился, помогите решить проблему с `$q`.

```
     $scope.addNew = function(){
       $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "includes/insert_data.php",
            data: {
                'title': $scope.notes.title,
                'text': $scope.notes.text,
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
        $http.get('includes/get_data.php')
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.notes = response.data.records;
        }); 
      }
```

Comment: Не надо. ````.````

Comment: я не понял простите

Comment: Не надо делать ajax-запросы синхронными. Используй `.then`. И да, промисы тоже асинхронные.

Comment: у меня такая проблема с 50% меняется данные без перезагрузки.

Comment: я кажется не правильно задал вопрос да? я должен сказать мне надо асинхронный код???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не надо делать этот код синхронным. Надо просто выполнять второй запрос после первого:

```
$scope.addNew = function () {
  $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "includes/insert_data.php",
    data: { title: $scope.notes.title, text: $scope.notes.text },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }).then(function () {
    $http.get('includes/get_data.php').then(function (response) {
      $scope.notes = response.data.records;
    });
  });
};
```

Также можно использовать chain'инг промисов:

```
$scope.addNew = function () {
  $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "includes/insert_data.php",
    data: { title: $scope.notes.title, text: $scope.notes.text },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  }).then(function () {
    return $http.get('includes/get_data.php');
  }).then(function (response) {
    $scope.notes = response.data.records;
  });
};
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!!!!!!!!!! помогли очень, уже 5 дня мучаюсь.

Comment: Что бы в дальнейшем не мучатся, читайте внимательно про ``$promise``. Хотя бы вот эту [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/189084/) для понимания

Comment: внутренний `then` можно было снаружи делать, чтобы вложенность не увеличивать

Comment: @Grundy, да, можно.

Comment: @ArmanGhazaryan, ответ дополнен.

Comment: Спасибо обязательно посмотрю.